# Delete a row from another sheet where text equals #N/A

Tags: excel, vba

I have built series of VBA macros to work through some steps for a user. I have built a button to for a user to click to remove any row that contains #N/A. One of my earlier steps makes this just a plain text value.

When executing the action it appears to run through but just moves my view to the worksheet i am trying to clean up and doesn't actually delete any rows.

I have tried switching parts of the code so instead of = to like

```
Sub DeleteNAsOnFrank_Click()
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long

With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

With Sheets("Frank Import Full List")
    .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
        With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value = "#N/A" Then .EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next Lrow
End With

ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With
End Sub
```

I expect it to delete any row that contains the text `If .Value = "#N/A" Then .EntireRow.Delete` on the `Sheets("Frank Import Full List")`

Comment: You know instead of looping and deleting, you could use Autofilter to delete all those rows in 1 go? `Sheets("Frank Import Full List").Range("A1:A" & Lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="#N/A"`

Comment: And use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba/11169920#11169920) to find the last row.

Comment: You're not deleting because your `If Not IsError(.Value)` is tripping because `#N/A` **is** an error. Remove that test and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
'Code...
For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(.Cells(Lrow, "A")) Then .Rows(Lrow).EntireRow.Delete
Next Lrow
'Code...
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to

```
    With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
        If IsError(.Value) Then .EntireRow.Delete
    End With
```

However, I would recommend a better way to delete those cells. Use Autofilter instead of looping and deleting. **Your code will be much more faster**. Also instead of usedrange. Work with the actual range. Use [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba/11169920#11169920) to find the last row and work with that range

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim delRange As Range
Dim lRow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Frank Import Full List")

With ws
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="#N/A"
        Set delRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
    End With

    If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.Delete

    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: How quick is using autofilter (your method) vs passing the range to an array and looping through that?

Comment: Best is to try and find it out yourself :) BTW Using array in this case is not advised as you will have to take care of 2 operations. clear array row and after transposing, take care of blanks. you could take care of the rows in the array itself but then still it is "2 operations".

Comment: True. I'll have to test and see for myself

Comment: Yup. BTW whether it is array or autofilter, they both are definitely better than deleting rows in a loop :D. There is one more way to delete rows using loop. It is called the Union mehod where you delete once the loop gets over.

Comment: Oh I agree all these methods listed are better than what I proposed... but it works ;)